# Optional key type not understood by flow in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

```
type A = { 
  foo : string,
  bar? : string,
}

type B = {
   foo : string,
   bar : string,
}
```

When an object of type B is assigned to a prop of type A, it triggers an error.

If my case is a normal behaviour, I don't understand this choice because it is not coherent with how flow handle type with more keys than specified type.

Is there a workaround for making this work ? Or is it synonym of bad design ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
var bObj: B = { foo: "", bar: "" };
var aObj: A = bObj;
```

the issue is that if this were allowed, it would be valid to do

```
aObj.bar = undefined;
```

because `aObj` has type `A` and `bar` is allowed to be `undefined` for objects of type `A`. If that were allowed, you'd *also* be modifying your `bObj` object, and it wouldn't actually match the type definition of `B` anymore.

> Is there a workaround for making this work?

There is! You need to tell Flow what *variance* is allowed in your object. In this case, you'd change

```
bar?: string,
```

to be

```
+bar?: string,
```

meaning that for objects of type `A`, the `bar` property should be considered *read-only*, which means that the concern above is no longer an issue.

Full example:

```
type A = { 
  foo : string,
  +bar?: string,
};
type B = {
   foo : string,
   bar : string,
};

var bObj: B = { foo: "", bar: "" };
var aObj: A = bObj;
```

([On Flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN5iphhRxxgBcYAzhgE4CWAdgOYA01MAGoARgEN2AfmZsufQQF8A3JlwEAQqQpC6DWRx4ChE9k1aGFqFegBuksKIDyogFbMtZSnuYAiX-yOkn6+YDb2ZuIu7kTazm7KQA))

Comment: It doesn't work with arrays thought? [On Flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN5iphhRxxgBcYAzhgE4CWAdgOYA01MAGoARgEN2AfmZsufQQF8A3JlwEAQqQpC6DWRx4ChE9k1aGFqFegBuksKIDyogFbNC7duKwAeDQB82gDalHrMAEQR-I6SkRFgigC6qvZm4i7uRF4+voRBZM5uykA)

Comment: @Alburkerk Then you'd want `$ReadOnlyArray<T>`: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN5iphhRxxgBcYAzhgE4CWAdgOYA01MAGoARgEN2AfmZsufQQF8A3JlwEAQqQpC6DWRx4ChE9k1aGFqFegBuksKIDyogFbNC7duKwAeDQB82gDalHrMAEQR-I6SkRFgigC6qvZm4i7uYAAkAEp44gAmTtwwWJ7efoRBZM5uykA